# "So must the X be" vs "So must be the X" vs Neither

Tags: grammaticality

I am not sure whether either of the following sentences (in quotations) are grammatically correct. They both sound awkward to me. Is anyone able to judge whether they are?

"Since the latter is large, so must the former **be**."

or

"Since the latter is large, so must **be** the former."

Comment: After 'must' can you use am, is, are? Now read this sentence without must. Since the latter is large, so is the former.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is another example of hyperbaton, like in the discussed sentence one swallow doe not spring make, or an example of inversion with the word " so",I think that this sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: Which sentence is grammatically correct? Please explain which is correct based on what reference/research you have to support your answer. One thing for sure is it is not an example of hyperbaton.

Comment: The first sentence is correct. The inversion is usual after so, and it is usually constructed in such a way: the first part of the verb, the subject and the remaining part of the verb.

Comment: You just said **this sentence is grammatically correct**. Please edit your post with relevant research or reference.

Comment: What do you mean by reference ? A particular grammar reference with the name of the author?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But in this particular case do you need the name of the author?

Comment: You are new to the community. It will take some time for you to learn how to answer appropriately. Please edit your post by clicking on **edit** with 1. The first sentence is correct, 2. Reasons why the first sentence is correct, 3. possible link or (any) reference to support your answer.

Comment: The syntax of the English Language by Smirnitsky,The inversion with "so", which usually has the expressive meaning.